# Get next object after selected object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

I need to create function that receives object with a `boolean` attribute, changes its value to `false`, then gets next item in array and changes its value to `true`. If provided object is the last item in the array, then we come back to the first item.

In other words, function should have these outcomes when invoked:

**Example 1**

```
const arr = [
  { 
   id: 1, 
   chosen: false 
  }, 
  { 
   id: 2, 
   chosen: true 
  }, 
  { 
   id: 3, 
   chosen: false 
  }, 
];

const chosenObject = arr[1];

functionToBeCreated(chosenObject); // Outcome: [{ id: 1, chosen: false }, { id: 2, chosen: false }, { id: 3, chosen: true }]
```

**Example 2**

```
const arr = [
  { 
   id: 1, 
   chosen: false 
  }, 
  { 
   id: 2, 
   chosen: false 
  }, 
  { 
   id: 3, 
   chosen: true 
  }, 
];

const chosenObject = arr[2];

functionToBeCreated(chosenObject); // Outcome: [{ id: 1, chosen: true }, { id: 2, chosen: false }, { id: 3, chosen: false }]
```

Do you have maybe any ideas how it can be archived?

Comment: Why do you need to do it this way? Why can you not pass the array and an index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See explanations thoughtout the code.

```js
const arr = [
  { 
   id: 1, 
   chosen: false 
  }, 
  { 
   id: 2, 
   chosen: true 
  }, 
  { 
   id: 3, 
   chosen: false 
  }, 
];

// This is your chosen pointer. It has to change, so it is not a constant
let chosenObject = 1;

function functionToBeCreated(chosen){

  // Set the currently chosen property to false
  arr[chosen].chosen = false
  
  // Determine the next object.
  // This is the remainder of the division by the length of the array
  // this is a zero-based index.
  let next = (chosen + 1) % arr.length
  
  // Set the "next" chosen property to true
  arr[next].chosen = true
  
  // Update your pointer
  chosenObject = next
};

// 1st call
functionToBeCreated(chosenObject)
console.log(arr)

// 2nd call
functionToBeCreated(chosenObject)
console.log(arr)

// 3rd call
functionToBeCreated(chosenObject)
console.log(arr)

// 4th call
functionToBeCreated(chosenObject)
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, step regarding determining of the next object with the usage of % was the key to this solution